# Button or link button event does not fire time to time

Tags: c#

In my whole project I have several events and surprising thing is that sometime some event fire up and sometime doesnot.I don't know hat is going on. I have tried many option after seraching from google. Please someone help me. I am in very bad situation.

```
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (Session["userid"] != null)
                {
                    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
                    {
                        string str = FileUpload1.FileName;
                        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(".") 
                        + "//images//" + str);

                        string path = "~//images//" + str.ToString();
                        con.Open();

                        Label1.Text = "File uploaded successfully";
                        main addinfo = new main();
                        string Id = Request.QueryString["id"];
                        string SQL = "insert into 
                        mandir(with_user,name,place,with_district,with_religion,
                        with_religion_category,description,photo)
                        values('" + Session["userid"] + "','" + txttemplename.Text.Trim() 
                        + "','" + txtaddress.Text.Trim() + "','" + 
                        ddldistrict.SelectedItem.Value + "','" + 
                        ddlreligion.SelectedItem.Value + "','" + 
                        ddlreligioncategory.SelectedItem.Value + 
                        "','" + txtdescription.Value + "','" + path + "')";

                        addinfo.saveData(SQL);
                        con.Close();

                        txttemplename.Text = "";
                        txtaddress.Text = "";
                        txtdescription.Value = "";

                        string message1 = "Thank you for providing the information";
                        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), 
                        "Popup", "ShowPopup('" + message1 + "');", true);

                        //  lblenquirymsg.Text = "";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Label1.Text = "File not uploaded successfully";
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    // lblinfo.Text = "You Must Login Or Register To give information";

                    string message = "You Must Login Or Register To Comment";
                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),
                    "Popup", "ShowPopup('" + message + "');", true);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", ex);
            }


 <div class="weltext">
        <h2>Add information</h2>
        <div>
          <div class="txt-st4" style="margin-bottom:8px; margin-top:10px;">Please fill the form below to provide information.</div>
          <div style="padding:0px 0 10px 0;">
            <form method="post">

              <div style="margin-bottom:3px;"></div>
              <div style="margin-bottom:7px;">
                  <div style="margin-bottom:3px;">Temple Name <span style="color:#F00">*<br />
                      </span><asp:TextBox ID="txttemplename" class="input_field1 verifyText" runat="server" style="margin-left: 0px" ></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>

                    <%--   <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
                   ErrorMessage="please input alphabets." ControlToValidate="txtfullname"
                    ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z]+$" Height="19px" Width="165px"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>--%>

                     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvtemplelname" runat="server" 
               ControlToValidate="txttemplename" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                  <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revtemplelname" runat="server"
                       ControlToValidate="txttemplename" ErrorMessage="Only alphabets are allowed"
                       ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z ]+$"  > </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

                     </div>


                 <div style="margin-bottom:4px;">
                <div class="field required">

              <div style="margin-bottom:3px;">

              Address<span style="color:#F00">*<br /></span>
              <asp:TextBox ID="txtaddress"  class="input_field1 verifyText" runat="server" style="margin-left: 0px"  ></asp:TextBox>
              <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvaddress" runat="server" 
               ControlToValidate="txtaddress" ErrorMessage="Please enter valid address"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>


                  <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revaddress" runat="server"
                       ControlToValidate="txtaddress" ErrorMessage="Only alphabets are allowed"
                       ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z ]+$"  > </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
              </div>
                    </div>
                     </div>
              <div style="margin-bottom:4px;">
                <div class="field required">

              <div style="margin-bottom:3px;">  Choose district  <span style="color:#F00">*<br />
                  </span><asp:DropDownList ID="ddldistrict" runat="server"  class="input_field1 verifyText" OnLoad="ddldistrict_Load" style="margin-left: 0px"></asp:DropDownList></div><div style="margin-bottom:4px;">
                <div class="field required">
                    <br />
                </div></div>


 <div style="margin-bottom:3px;">  Choose religion<span style="color:#F00">*<br />
     </span><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlreligion"  class="input_field1 verifyText" runat="server" OnLoad="ddlreligion_Load" style="margin-left: 0px"></asp:DropDownList></div><div style="margin-bottom:4px;">
                <div class="field required">
                    <br />
                </div></div>


          <div style="margin-bottom:3px;">  Choose religion category  <span style="color:#F00">*<br />
              </span><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlreligioncategory" class="input_field1 verifyText" runat="server" OnLoad="ddlreligioncategory_Load" style="margin-left: 0px" ></asp:DropDownList>
              </div><div style="margin-bottom:4px;">
                <div class="field required">
<br />
                    </div></div>






                    <%--<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" 
                         ErrorMessage="please input alphabets." ControlToValidate="txtaddress" 
                         ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z]+$" Height="19px" Width="165px"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>--%>

                       </div>
              </div>
               <div style="margin-bottom:3px;">Description<span style="color:#F00">*</span></div>
              <div style="margin-bottom:4px;">
                <div class="field required">

                    <textarea id="txtdescription" runat="server" name="description" class="text_area" style="width: 532px; height: 180px"></textarea>


         <%--      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvdescription" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtdescription"
           ErrorMessage="*" InitialValue="Select"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revdescription" Runat="server"
               ErrorMessage="ERROR: Please enter a valid description<br/>" SetFocusOnError="true" Display="Dynamic"
               ControlToValidate="txtdescription" ValidationGroup="MandatoryContent"
               ValidationExpression="^[A-Za-z'\-\p{L}\p{Zs}\p{Lu}\p{Ll}\']+$"
               ForeColor="Red"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>--%>


                      </div>
              </div>



            Choose picture:<br />
            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" style="margin-left: 0px" /><br />
              <%--    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Upload Image" onclick="Button1_Click" /><br >--%>

              <br />

              <span style="color:#F00">
              <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
              <span style="color:#F00">

                  <div id="dialog" style="display: none">
</div>
                  <asp:Button id="btnSubmit" Text="Submit " runat="server" class="btn" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"  />
                 <%--<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" runat="server"   value="Submit Now"  class="btn" CausesValidation="False"  style="margin-left: 13px" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"  />--%>
              <br />
              </span>
              </span>

<br />




               <div>
                   <%--  <asp:Button ID="btnReset" Text="Reset Form" runat="server" value="Reset Form" class="btn" OnClick="btnReset_Click"  />--%>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblenquirymsg" runat="server"></asp:Label>

              </div>

            </form>
              </div>
            </div>

<p>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblenquirymsg1" runat="server"></asp:Label>

              </p>
```

The above event is also not firing.

Comment: PLease post your problem area

Comment: Please post your aspx code also. May be you are using requiredfieldvalidator that is why your page is not post back.

Comment: yes I have used that.If I remove the requiredfield validator also it doesnot work.